# How to Share AWS SES Identities across Organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

i started using SES with a single User account. Now i created a organization, invited a colleague, created a Operations group, put him in it and attached the FullAWSAccess - Policy.

I want to ensure that he can see and manage our S3 Accounts and especially the SES Identities i created in the past.
Unfortunately this doesn't work. 
Any idea what i am missing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your colleague login in your account containing the SES service or another one? Is your colleague able to administrate the S3 buckets that are in the same account?

Comment: @lolops can you share the error message they are getting when sending SES across accounts?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can allow any other account to send SES emails from your AWS account. You will need to grant them the proper permission which according to your question, has already been done.

Also they need to send the email as a *delegated sender*. This can be done from the API or any of the client libraries.

More details on the endpoints for you here:

- [Sending Emails for the Identity Owner for Amazon SES Sending Authorization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-authorization-delegate-sender-tasks-email.html)
- [Amazon SES Now Supports Cross-Account Sending](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/07/amazon-ses-now-supports-cross-account-sending/)

Comment: Thank you very much, your answers don't really cover my question, see my own answer. Enjoy the bounty ;)

Answer (score 4):

First, I'd like to rephrase the question (using AWS terminology) from what I understood: *How to enable cross-account access to specific AWS services (e.g. S3 or SES) using AWS Organizations?*

From reading "FullAWSAccess - Police" I assume the OP tried to use AWS Service Control Policies. These are not meant to be used to grant cross-account access. Instead, the AWS docs state that "SCPs offer central control over the **maximum available permissions** for all accounts in your organization". [1] When you look at the *policy evaluation logic* chart in the docs [7], you'll find that an SCP will never cause a final *Allow* decision and skips the (implicit) deny at best. You still need a resource-based policy or an identity-based policy which leads to a final *Allow* decision.

Thus, the correct way of delegating access is to create a custom IAM role. [2]
This envolves the following steps which are also outlined in the docs [2]:

1. You create a role *SesCrossAccountAccess* and establish trust between the original account and the colleague's account.
2. You grant the new role access to the SES actions [3] needed by attaching an inline policy to the role. (note: this is the *identity-based policy* approach)
3. You must ensure that the IAM user in your colleague's account has permission to *assume* the new role.
4. Your colleague might switch to the *SesCrossAccountAccess* role using the AWS Management Console in the browser or via the assume AWS CLI command [4].
5. If this is not working, please make sure there are no explicit denies somewhere along the policy evaluation logic chain [7].

This concept has nothing to do with AWS Organizations in particular.
However, you could reference your organization identifier instead of the account number inside the IAM role's trust policy using the `aws:PrincipalOrgID` condition key [5]. This concept is also outlined as "Limiting or extending access to a role based on AWS Organizations" in an AWS security blog post [6]. It simplifies the permission management if there are multiple colleagues who need access to the cross-account role.

The best answer mentions the use of the Amazon SES Sending Authorization feature. I am not sure if that is applicable in this case because as far as I understood, the OP wants to "**manage the SES identities**" - which is something different than using them (i.e. SendEmail and SendRawEmail actions).

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html
[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonses.html#amazonses-actions-as-permissions
[4] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html
[5] https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/security/control-access-to-aws-resources-by-using-the-aws-organization-of-iam-principals/
[6] https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/security/how-to-use-trust-policies-with-iam-roles/
[7] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#policy-eval-denyallow

Comment: Thank you - this cleared up a lot of my confusion about the AWS permissions model, I've awarded you the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

I want to answer it as I researched another few hours:
even when using organizations, other users cannot manage the already verified Emails.
My error was using the root account. By manage i mean log into the AWS Management Console and view/edit the addresses,

As far as i can tell you need to create a separate IAM User (e.g. call it shared-ses-user), which than can be shared. This is not a good solution but at least we can make it work.